# Storing and comparing grid patterns

Tags: javascript, mongodb, design-patterns, multidimensional-array

I have a 2 dimensional array that stores pattern information. The data may look something like this:

[image]

```
var testGrid = [["blank", "red", "blank"],
/* row 2 */ ["blank", "yellow", "green"],
/* row 3 */ ["blank", "blue", "blank"]];
```

The max pattern size is a 3 by 3 grid, however, not all spaces have to be used. Since blanks basically mean that there is no information there, I regularly encounter scenarios where two patterns are structured differently, but are functionally the same. Like this:

```
[["red", "red" "blank"],
["red", "red", "blank"], 
["blank", "blank", "blank"]

[["blank", "blank", "blank"],
["blank", "red", "red"],
["blank", "red", "red"]]
```

All patterns would have 4 possible representations due to orientation. However, some patterns like this one below:

[image]

```
[["blank", "blank", "blank"],
["blank", "yellow", "green"],
["blank", "blue", "blank"]]
```

would have 8 possible representations in a 3 by 3 grid.

So I have a few questions:

1. What would be the best way to store this data? I was thinking I could store the more simple patterns as a 2 by 2 grid, which would reduce the amount of checks I would have to do on those to the normal 4.
2. What is the best way to check against patterns already in the database? Just loop through a function that compares the newly created pattern to every other entry in the database? (I'm using a mongoDB by the way).

Comment: how many colors? and wich 8 representations do you mean? rotated around the center, ok, that are 4, and then? mirrored? translated?

Comment: sorry, I mean translated

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use number(hex/decimal) to encode a color and store. So if `blank = 0, red = 1, green = 2, yellow = 3`

Then

```
["blank", "yellow", "green"] = "032"
```